# Get xml attribute with XDocument based on value of another xml attribute

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have some xml that looks something like:

```
<forms>
    <form name="admin" title="Admin Info">
        <field name="primary" label="Primary Name" required="false">
        <group desc="General" name="personalinfo" required="false" hide="false">
            <field label="Photos" name="photoupload" required="false" hide="false">
            <field label="First Name" name="firstanme" required="false" hide="false">
        </group>
    </form>
    <form name = "..." etc>
        ....etc...
    </form>
</forms>
```

I am trying to get information from the inner "field" tag.  For example, I want to get the "required" and "hide" values when name="photoupload."

What I have so far:

```
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlTemplate);
        var photoInfo = doc.Descendants("field")
                                .Where(field => field.Attribute("name").Value == "photoupload")
                                .Select(field => new
                                {
                                    Hide = field.Attribute("hide").Value,
                                    Required = field.Attribute("required").Value
                                })
                                .Single();

        photoInfoTextBox.Text = photoInfo.Hide.ToString();
```

However, I am getting an "`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`" error.  My guess is that the code is trying to get info from the first "field" tag (where name="primary"), but actually I want info from the inner field tag, specifically:

forms/form(where name="admin")/group(where desc="general")/field(where name="photoupload").

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use casting instead of reading `Value` property:

```
    var photoInfo = doc.Descendants("field")
                       .Where(field => (string)field.Attribute("name") == "photoupload")
                       .Select(field => new {
                                Hide = (bool?)field.Attribute("hide"),
                                Required = (bool?)field.Attribute("required")
                       })
                       .Single();
```

Most likely you have an exception because some `field` element don't have `name` attribute. That means `field.Attribute("name")` will return `null`. And `null.Value` will throw `NullReferenceException`. Note that some elements also don't have `hide` attribute.

When you cast `XAttribute` or `XElement` to type which can have `null` value, you will get `null` if attribute or element do not exist. No exceptions will be thrown.

NOTE: Thus you have only one `field` with given name, you can simply try get that field

```
var photoUpload = doc.Descendants("field")
                     .Single(f => (string)f.Attribute("name") == "photoupload");

// or
var photoUpload = doc.XPathSelectElement("//field[@name='photoupload']");
```

Comment: Wow thank you! I was still having issues trying the first part of your comment, using casting.  However, you are correct, the field I need has a unique name so I can get it directly using your methods.  And then I can just use var isRequired = photoupload.Attribute("required");  Thanks!

Comment: @Rohhan if it's possible that there is no field with given name in document, then you can use `SingleOrDefault` instead of `Single` and check if result is `null` before reading other attribute values.